# Improvement of generic arguments with reflection

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

Here is a simplification of an Http-Client that I'm currently working on:

```
class Request[A]( val url: String, val event: Callbacks[A] )
{
    def run: Try[A] = ...
}
case class Image( override val url: String, override val event: Callbacks[Bitmap] ) extends Request[Bitmap]
```

---

```
object GET
{
    def apply[A <: Request[B] : ClassTag, B : ClassTag]( url: String, event: Callbacks[B] ): Try[B] =
    {
        classOf[A]
            .runtimeClass
            .getConstructor( classOf[String], classOf[Callbacks[B]] )
            .newInstance( url, event )
            .asInstanceOf[A]
            .run
    }
}
```

---

```
object Main extends App
{
    GET[Image, Bitmap]( "http://...", null )
}
```

I would like to improve my API to the effect that I can make the `GET` call like this:

```
GET[Image]( "http://...", null )
```

Supplying the generic Argument `Image` should imply that I'm working with a `Bitmap` and therefore I don't want to specify it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pattern similar to `CanBuildFrom`: Use an implicit builder which creates a suitable `Request`:

Some types:

```
abstract class Content

class Bitmap extends Content

class Callbacks[T]

abstract class Request[C <: Content](val url: String, val event: Callbacks[C]) {
  def run: C
}

class ImageRequest(_url: String, _event: Callbacks[Bitmap]) 
  extends Request[Bitmap](_url, _event) {

  def run: Bitmap = {
    new Bitmap()
  }
}
```

now the types for the implicit argument `RequestBuilder`:

```
abstract class RequestBuilder[C <: Content] {
  def create(url: String, event: Callbacks[C]): Request[C]
}

class ImageRequestBuilder extends RequestBuilder[Bitmap]() {
  def create(url: String, event: Callbacks[Bitmap]): ImageRequest = {
    new ImageRequest(url, event)
  }
}

object ImplicitContainer {
  implicit val ImplicitImageRequestBuilder = new ImageRequestBuilder()
}
```

to be used like this:

```
object GET {
  def apply[C <: Content](url: String, event: Callbacks[C])
                         (implicit rb: RequestBuilder[C]): C = {
    rb.create(url, event).run
  }
}

object HttpClient extends App {
  import ImplicitContainer._

  val bitmap = GET[Bitmap]("http://...", null)
  println(bitmap)
}
```

This way you always get *different requests* when you call `GET`.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could get is providing an implicit parameter and register all my result mappers (Image, Html, ...) as implicit values. This adds some configuration overhead due to the additional implicit definitions but yields the advantage of better customization. This way I'm also getting rid off the reflection part.

```
implicit val image = Image.apply _
```

---

```
object GET
{
    def apply[T]( url: String, event: Callbacks[T] )( implicit request: ( String, Callbacks[T] ) => Request[T] ): Try[T] =
    {
        request( url, event ).run
    }
}
```

---

```
import image

GET[Bitmap]( "http://...", null )
GET[Bitmap]( "http://...", null )( myOwnAwesomeImageProcessor _ )
```